# How do i create a simple subroutine to find and print a user's inputed age?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def findAge(userAge):
userAge = int(input("Enter your age please: "))
return userAge

age = findAge()
print(age)
```

what am i doing wrong, I literally have no clue! Can somebody please also explain to me which variable names i can change and keep the same!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you defined your function with a parameter, which you don't need. Your function is working without it. If you are coming from a C background and think of your parameter as some kind of pointer, please forget about it. You define a local variable inside of the function and initialise it with the user input.

Now you only need to take care of your indentation, see the code snippet below. The following should work on your machine as it works on my, too:

```
def findAge():
    userAge = int(input("Enter your age please: "))
    return userAge

age = findAge()
print(age)
```

Here are some further readings suggestions:

- [Python3 functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_functions.htm)
- [Code Indentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) (PEP 8)

Hope I could help you. Have a nice day.

**Update**

If you do need a parameter and you want to modify it, do something like this:

```
def get_older(age):
    age += 1
    return age

my_age = 5
my_age = get_older(my_age)
print(my_age) # 6
```

Another example using parameter, but slightly different:

```
def print_name_age(name):
    age = int(input("How old are you {name}?"))
    print(f"Ah, so you are {age} years old, {name}?")

print_name_age("Michael")
```

**Note**

f-Strings are only available for Python 3.6 or higher. If you are using another Python 3 version, replace the print-statement with the following:

```
print("Ah, so you are {} years old, {}?".format(age, name))
```

Comment: Thank you soo much! But when would i need parameters (sorry, I am a beginner.)

Comment: Updated my answer and hope it'll help you. You should definitely check out the provided links for further information and search for some tutorials to get deeper into the world of Python. There are many great ones out there. Have a nice day!

Comment: @TahreenAkther: Parameters are how you can pass information to a function, but in your case the function gets everything it needs from the user, so there's no reason to have a parameter.